# Creating actions based on local location/rotation/scale of an object

Tags: animation, keyframes, actions

This may be a noob question, but I couldn't find the answer around.
I am trying to create a set of actions that I would like to apply to different object. The issue I have is that if the action includes the 'location' keyframe then the animation brings the object back to where the action was created. Here there's an example:

The yellow cube has a 2 keyframe animation, it simply moves down of 1 unit from its current location.
[image: screen_1]

If I apply the same Action to the blue cube and I click play, the blue cube gets the same location of the yellow cube, instead of simply going down by 1 unit from it current location.

How can make it work in a way that I can apply an action to any object and that will work based on the location/rotation/scale of the object?

I hope the question is clear, thanks for reading!

Comment: Will take a guess that you have keyframed all location channels x, y and z, (via I Loc) whereas it sounds like you simply wish to keyframe the z channel.  Either remove the X and Y channel keyframes, or use the diamond next to (or hit I over) the z channel only when adding keyframes  (alternatively use delta location as answered below.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just animate the delta transform instead of the location, then you can link the animation data to the other cube. This works.

[image]

if you need a step by step explanation for this, just let me know.

Comment: Thank you so much! I tried using the delta before, but it wouldn't make the cube moving. It's kind of weird: the cube doesn't move and both keyframes have a "location z:0" if I set the keyframe from the viewport, pressing "i" and selecting "delta location" from the menu. Instead, the cube moves correctly if I set the keyframes adding the location value on the tab that's on your screenshot. Why is that?

Comment: can you please check the checkmark on the left of my answer? thank you.

Comment: Just did it! Thank you again, I guess that the viewport keyframe issue I mentioned in my comment is a bug?